# Должным образом не работает nth-child() -_-

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Хочу первому и последнему 'blog-content-info' сделать margin-left: 50px;, но не получается. А если получается, то второму никак этот margin не убрать. Прошу помочь мне с этой сложной(для меня) задачей. Буду благодарен за помощь и уделенное вами мне время)

P.S. Должно быть так, как на фотографии

```css
.blog-content {
    display: flex;
}

.blog-content-img {
    width: 50%;
}

.blog-content-info {
    width: 50%;
}

.blog-content-info:nth-child(1),
.blog-content-info:nth-child(3) {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.blog-content-info:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class='section'>
        <div class="page-services">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="main-inner">
                    <div class="main-inner-title">Blog</div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
                </div>

                <div class="blog">
                    <div class="blog-content">
                        <img class="blog-content-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KuOA3P0xdmw/hqdefault.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="blog-content-info">
                            <p>SEO Quis Vestibulum</p>

                            <p>Dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="blog-content">
                        <div class="blog-content-info">
                            <p>SEO Quis Vestibulum</p>

                            <p>Dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...</p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="blog-content-img" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/768/1*8W7fjHZhKf4BT3WEHCy7EQ.jpeg" alt="">

                    </div>

                    <div class="blog-content">
                        <img class="blog-content-img" src="https://sun9-20.userapi.com/impf/c624429/v624429082/31090/N1UJgpDTlqo.jpg?size=640x480&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=a970ad1f154973bec86364202b9915ae&c_uniq_tag=l2KMz72TrcQvaSIzMY_Fxv1D5x25QvoUanm9gwMJtxA&type=album" alt="">
                        <div class="blog-content-info">
                            <p>SEO Quis Vestibulum</p>

                            <p>Dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:nth-child надо указать для .blog-content

```
.blog .blog-content:nth-child(1) .blog-content-info,
.blog .blog-content:nth-child(3) .blog-content-info {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```css
.blog-content {
    display: flex;
}

.blog-content-img {
    width: 50%;
}

.blog-content-info {
    width: 50%;
}

.blog .blog-content:nth-child(1) .blog-content-info,
.blog .blog-content:nth-child(3) .blog-content-info {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section class='section'>
        <div class="page-services">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="main-inner">
                    <div class="main-inner-title">Blog</div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
                </div>

                <div class="blog">
                    <div class="blog-content">
                        <img class="blog-content-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KuOA3P0xdmw/hqdefault.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="blog-content-info">
                            <p>SEO Quis Vestibulum</p>

                            <p>Dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="blog-content">
                        <div class="blog-content-info">
                            <p>SEO Quis Vestibulum</p>

                            <p>Dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...</p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="blog-content-img" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/768/1*8W7fjHZhKf4BT3WEHCy7EQ.jpeg" alt="">

                    </div>

                    <div class="blog-content">
                        <img class="blog-content-img" src="https://sun9-20.userapi.com/impf/c624429/v624429082/31090/N1UJgpDTlqo.jpg?size=640x480&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=a970ad1f154973bec86364202b9915ae&c_uniq_tag=l2KMz72TrcQvaSIzMY_Fxv1D5x25QvoUanm9gwMJtxA&type=album" alt="">
                        <div class="blog-content-info">
                            <p>SEO Quis Vestibulum</p>

                            <p>Dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```